# Every field has at least two elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

I got a question saying in every field (F, +, ⋅, 0, 1), the set F has at least 2 elements. It asks if it is true prove it or if false provide a counterexample.

I understand the idea of finite fields {0, 1} always having at least two elements but does this prove that it is true?

Comment: The axioms of a field often include $0\neq 1$, i.e. the additive identity is not the multiplicative identity.  This is a reasonable restriction because otherwise (if $0 = 1$) there will only be one element in the underlying set and the arithmetic will be "trivial".

Comment: For fun (or $F_{un}$), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element

Answer (score 4):

In a field $(F, +, \cdot)$, the nonzero elements must form a group with multiplication. Hence, $(F-\{0\}, \cdot)$ must be an Abelian group.

As such, this group must have a neutral element, $1$. Since $1 \in F-\{0\}$, $1$ cannot be $0$.

Answer (score 3):

One of the field axioms is that $0 \neq 1$. Q.E.D.

Comment: That is a lemma, but i did an alternative proof to prove 0 = 1 and it worked

Comment: @JerryMichaels What did you prove?

Comment: So a previous question i was given said is 0 = 1 true? i wrote that if we assume x = y then x^2 = xy, then x^2 = y^2 = xy-y^2 then x + y = y, since x = y we get 2y=y, and since we started with y being a nonzero subtract 1 from both sides and we get 1 = 0

Comment: @JerryMichaels It's never true in a field

Comment: I don't understand what you proved

Comment: Oh maybe your right. If a lemma says that 0 cannot equal 1 then i should follow it. Thanks you.

Comment: @JerryMichaels It's not a lemma it's an axiom