# Show that the given sets are the generating sets.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For the vector space, $F^X$ show that the set $\{f : 0 \in \text{range of } f\}$ is a generating set provided ***$X$ has at least two elements*** and $\{f : 0 \in \text{range of } f\}$ is a generating set provided ***$F$ has at least 3 elements***.

Here I didn't understand the highlighted part in the previous paragraph. Could anyone explain those highlighted parts and please guide me on how to proceed with this one.

**Additional Details:**
$F$ is a field and $X$ is a set, so $F^X$ is the F-vector space of functions $f:X→F$ equipped with the pointwise operations of addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: What are $F$ and $X$?  Just sets?  But then, how is $F^X$ a vector space?

Comment: I think $F$ just represent the function space but I am not sure about $X$. But it could be used to represent multivariate function space if X is a vector.

Comment: $F$ is a field and $X$ is a set, so $F^{X}$ is the $F$-vector space of functions $f:X \rightarrow F$ equipped with the pointwise operations of addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: @AxyuS It's your question.  If you don't know what your terms mean, it is going to be hard for you to make much progress.

Comment: The description provided by @KevinLópezAquino is correct.

Answer (score 1):

[Every field has at least two elements,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327821/every-field-has-at-least-two-elements) so let's assume that $|F| = 2.$ Given that $|X| = 0,$ we have that $X$ is empty, so vacuously, we can define a function $f : X \to F$ by specifying that for each element $x$ in $X,$ we have that $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = 1$ but not both. Of course, $X$ is empty, so either one will work, and there is no guarantee that the function $f$ has $f(x) = 0.$ One can make the same argument in the case that $|X| = 1.$ Consequently, if either $|X| \leq 1$ or $|F| = 2,$ then the claim does not hold because some function is not an $F$-linear combination of functions with $0$ in their range. We will assume that neither $|X| \leq 1$ nor $|F| = 2,$ i.e., $|X| \geq 2$ and $|F| \geq 3.$

Consider a function $f : X \to F.$ Certainly, if $f(x) = 0$ for some element $x \in X,$ then $f$ can be written as an $F$-linear combination of functions $f : X \to F$ such that $0$ is in the range of $f$: namely, $f$ is an $F$-linear combination of $f$ itself. Consequently, we may assume that $f(x) \neq 0$ for any element $x \in X.$ By hypothesis that $|X| \geq 2,$ given any element $x \in X,$ there exist functions $g_{f, x}, h_{f, x} : X \to F$ such that $g_{f, x}(y) = 0$  and $h_{f, x}(y) = f(y)$ whenever $y \neq x,$ $g_{f, x}(x) = f(x),$ and $h_{f, x}(x) = 0.$ Consequently, we may write $f = g_x + h_x,$ so the set $V = \{g_{f, x}, h_{f, x} \,|\, f \in F^X \}$ generates $F^X$ as an $F$-vector space. Further, the set $Z = \{f : X \to F \,|\, 0 \text{ is in the range of } f\}$ contains $V$ as a subset, hence the set $Z = Z \cup V$ generates $F^X$ as an $F$-vector space. QED.